# Calling a nested function from another script

Tags: javascript, jquery

In context I have two javascript files, one handles the actual page itself while another handles a popup tutorial. Each script file is nested within a function as shown below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // script here
}());
```

In the main script is the following function:

```
function updateCompView(ident) {
    'use script';
    // code is here
}
```

However what I'm finding is that if I reference this function within the second script file (for the tutorial) like so:

```
updateCompView('KL-COM-001');
```

I get an Uncaught ReferenceError. I have managed to resolve this by removing the top-level function however this then means I get a large number of 'use strict' JSLint errors.

Is there a way to reference functions that are nested within an external function?

Comment: You'll probably want to read up on scopes and closures in JS.

Comment: You'll have to make it referenceable, for example, do `if (!window.myNamespace) window.myNamespace = {}` then set `window.myNamespace.updateCompView = updateCompView;` and now you can access it as `window.myNamespace.updateCompView` from outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make it referenceable

There are three ways to do this, so lets start assuming you have the following code

```
(function () { // this is an IIFE
    "use strict";
    function baz() {}
}()); // this is where it gets invoked
```

---

**Method 1**, make your own namespace (just an *Object*), at the beginning of the *IIFE*,

```
if (!window.myNamespace)
    window.myNamespace = {};
```

then after `baz` is defined,

```
window.myNamespace.baz = baz;
```

Now you can access `baz` via `window.myNamespace.baz` under other closures

---

**Method 2**, `return` out of an *IIFE*, at the end of the *IIFE* you do

```
return baz; // or some object containing baz
```

and you refactor your *IIFE* to look like this

```
var foo = (function () {
    // IIFE body
}());
```

Now you can access `baz` via `foo` in the closure and descendant closures of where `foo` was `var`d

---

**Method 3**, set `baz` in the global namespace

There are two options for this, one is to structure it as a function expression and don't `var` the variable you assign to, i.e.

```
baz = function () {};
```

The other way is similar to method 1 but without the namespace. This can be considered bad in that it is polluting the global namespace with something new each time you do it. After `baz` is defined,

```
window.baz = baz;
```

Now you can access `baz` via `window.baz` or simply `baz` if it's not shadowed under other closures

Comment: Thanks for that, works perfectly. I had a vague idea of why it wasn't working but a lot of the posts online were overly complicated. This is the exact answer I was looking for, thanks!